# I can't access NEI

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't Access NEI, even though I have the mod installed.  I can't find the options tab, and the items or the options tab doesn't show.

Comment: Can you give us a screen shot of your game when the inventory screen is open?

Comment: Press o when you're in the inventory.

Comment: How do I send a screenshot

Comment: @XCrafted 1 Month late, but whatever... Make sure that your MC is not in fullscreen mode, open your inv, then press the `PrtSc` keyboard key. Upload it to an image sharing site like [imgur](www.imgur.com), and send us the links.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing "O" when in your inventory
(NOTE - It doesn't show when in creative inventory)
Also, do you get a "..." button in the top right of containers (when opened)?

Comment: It does show on the survival tab of the creative inventory.

Comment: It does? Whenever I go into the creative menu it isn't there, must be a new update or something. (I'm on about item list on the right).

Answer (score 0):

NEI is meant to be a survival mod (technically cheating) but can be accessed by pressing "O" in the survival inventory. From there, you can press/hold shift to get an infinite stack of whatever (as long as you open your inventory before 128 is gone). To change these, you must go to the "mods" section of the options screen. You can mess around with all the mods you have installed to minecraft. You select "Not Enough Items" and go from there

Comment: This does not cover anything new in regards to the question. Also, the `mods` section in MCF does not allow you to configure mod configurations.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if you use NEI you need to also have the mod CodeChickenCore to be able to run NEI.
After you've put both of them in the mods folder and started a minecraft world, if you're in creative you cannot access it unless you press the chest tab on the bottom right(as seen in image). 
This tab is almost like your inventory will look like in Survival Mode, except id doesn't have the crafting grid.
Once you've opened that tab you should be able to see NEI.
If you're in survival, then the NEI will be shown.
If it doesn't show in survival, try pressing the "O".

(NOTE:the image is from Vanilla minecraft so there isn't an <kbd>Options</kbd> tab there. Once you have both of the mods in the mods folder it will show it though.)
[image: Inventory in Creative Mode]

Answer (score 0):

Pressing O should work. If not, go into options\video settings and make sure the key under NEI is bound.

Comment: This adds nothing not already said.

Comment: You didn't add that the key might not be bound.